# Filter JSON data based on current URL route

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-routing

**The problem**

I'm trying to filter json data and display only a portion of it on an Angular page, based on the page's current URL.

**In detail**

I have a list of 100 JSON objects, and each one looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "Evangeline Perreault",
  "age_1": 1,
  "total_age": 1,
  "photo_small": "img/400/001_400.jpg",
  "photo_medium": "img/800/001_800.jpg",
  "photo_large": "img/1200/001_1200.jpg",
  "photo_extralarge": "img/1600/001_1600.jpg",
  "video": 67443664,
  "id": 1,
  "quote": "test quote here and here",
  "type": 1
},
```

The 'type' attribute is what I want to use to filter out the subsets of my data. With that in mind, I tried to setup my URL structure to tie the type attribute here to my url. Here is my route:

```
angular.module('100_Ages', ['mydirectives', 'ngResponsiveImages']).
    config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/100_Ages/nav/:personType', {templateUrl: 'partials/person-list.html', controller: NavListCtrl}).
        otherwise({redirectTo: '/100_Ages'});
    }]);
```

So, I have pointed the route to the 'type' field in my JSON and I tried writing a controller to tie the two together.

```
function NavListCtrl($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
  $http.get('person.json').success(function(data) {
  angular.forEach(data, function(person) {
          if (person.type == $routeParams.personType) 
            $scope.person = person;
        });
  });
}
```

And here is my partial template:

`<div class="nav_outer"><img class="nav_img" ng-src="{{person.photo_small}}" ng-alt="{{person.name}}" /></div>`

I expected this to display all the matching images for the URL type I'm on. So, if I'm on "/100_Ages/nav/3", I expected all the images (roughly 10 pictures) from the objects with a type of "3" to display. However, it only displayed the last object with a type of "3".

So, I tried an `ng-repeat` like so:

```
<div class="nav_outer" ng-repeat="person in persons"><img class="nav_img" ng-src="{{person.photo_small}}" ng-alt="{{person.name}}" /></div>
```

I expected that to loop through and show all the matching images, but that made nothing at all show up.

I think my problem has to do with the `angular.forEach`, but I'm not sure how else to tie my JSON type to the page's typeid.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ng-repeat` should work if you push each item into an array. (Also, you are referring to a 'persons' object in the ng-repeat, which doesn't exist according to code provided). So, try this:

```
$http.get('person.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.persons = [];
    angular.forEach(data, function(person) {
        if (person.type == $routeParams.personType) 
            $scope.persons.push(person);
            // or alternatively - this.push(person), with the optional 3rd param of $scope.persons (I don't really understand that, but whatever...)
    });
});
```

Now with the array populated, your `ng-repeat="person in persons"` should work.

**UPDATE:**

If the success object was already an array of objects, then just set the scope object to the array - no need to iterate through them:

```
$http.get('person.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.persons = data;    
})
```

Comment: Yes! That worked! Thank you. I'm curious, I had all of my JSON objects in one array, so why do I have to put each one into its own array for ng-repeat to work? Is that to get around the problem of it displaying only one result per type? Thanks again!